# Is it possible to find the corresponding task_struct from struct page?

Tags: linux, kernel

Is there a method of finding the corresponding struct task_struct by given struct page?
What i want to do is that i want to know which KVM virtual machine is using the given page in virtualization environment. And task_struct is added a new data member (i.e. vm_id) so that i can get the vm id once i get the task_struct by the given struc page.
There seems to be no a direct solution. But i have no idea about it.

So, what is the correct way of doing such things?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Considering there is a Page Frame Reclaiming Algorithm implemented in the Linux Kernel. To implement PFRA, there are data structures used by the kernel to find all the Page Table entries which are using the same page which is going to be reclaimed. When page table is located, the task_struct should be also located if CONFIG_MM_OWNER defined.

The page mapping to mm_struct may be 1:N, page mapping to task_struct also may be 1:N.

In file ./mm/rmap.c, function try_to_unmap_anon() and try_to_unmap_file(), there are codes which do the reverse mapping work from page struct to mm_struct.

One can refer to Chapter 17, in Understanding Linux Kernel, 3rd Edition for PFRA implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

In linux a kvm vm is a normale process with a pid a many vm struct as normal task, to archive what you want, i think you need to write a kernel module and do something like this [Walking page tables of a process in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980193/walking-page-tables-of-a-process-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

In general, no, since many pages are shared between multiple tasks/processes (shared libraries, multiple instances of a program running, etc.). I'm not familiar enough with the kernel structures to propose an alternative solution, though, so I'll let someone else answer that bit...

Comment: In fact, we could find tasks using specific page. That's what "reverse mapping" does.