# Physical Page Numbers for an arbitrary process

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

I have process `i` and I want to know if that process has physical pages in memory [zone](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mmzone.h#L327) `z`.

I know how to do a [page table walk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980193/walking-page-tables-of-a-process-in-linux) if I have a given address; however, since those all require some sort of virtual address.

I know the beginning page of `z` from `z -> zone_start_pfn` and it's end from `zone_end_pfn(z)` and reading seems to indicate that reverse mapping isn't available.

So what is the easy way to determine if process `i` has PPNs in zone `z`?

I want to do this in kernel space if that makes things easier.

Comment: You could try to work with physical addresses though. There are macros: _ _pa( ) and _ _va( ) which convert virtual address of a process to its physical address and back. It might be first step to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily from user space using [pagemap API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt).

Comment: Unfortunately, that is for user space and not for kernel space.