# How to protect a page so that it cannot be write in mips arch?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I want use pte_wrportect func to protect an address which ioremap return.

```
char * addr;
addr = ioremap(0x207f700000,PAGE_SIZE);
```

how to do next ?

Comment: You need to walk down the page table to get the pte and write the protect bit. Note that you don't have t worry about synchronization, since ioremap addresses are not cached.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8980193/1216776  However some functions have changed in recent kernels.

Comment: Note that this protection is fairly useless. Presumably your code doesn't write to the protected address. Any other kernel code that subsequently calls ioremap will set the protection to read-write

Comment: In the code, make sure that only I can ioremap once. I made the modification and verified it under KDB with mm8 addr 0xfafafa.The write operation was successful.why？

Answer (score 0):

Use the function

```
int set_memory_ro(unsigned long addr, int numpages)
```

use

`#include <linux/set_memory.h>`

Comment: yes it works.but it only for x86 . i need all arch.  mips x86 ppc arm32 .

Comment: sorry，my kernel version too low.  news support for arm arm64 x86 ppc but no mips

Comment: @liuye this function is not limited for x86, and should work in all archs. which kernel version are you using